# Links del centro de ayuda apuntando al sitio en inglés

Tags: soporte

En [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) existen algunos links que apuntan al sitio en inglés que debería estar apuntando al sitio en esapñol:

- > Por favor busca si tu [pregunta ya fue publicada antes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

  Debería apuntar a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates
- > QPreguntas que sean muy amplias, poco claras, incompletas o basadas en opinión pueden ser [puestas en espera por la comunidad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) hasta que sean mejoradas.

  Debería apuntar a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions, además que sobra una **Q** en **QPreguntas**
- > [Haz clic aquí para ver consejos sobre cómo hacer buenas preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y atraigan buenas respuestas.

  Debería apuntar a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- > Ver: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

  Debería apuntar a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Además en el título le sobre un punto **"."** que se encuentra dentro del link.
- > Esto puede ser muchas veces evitado al identificar e inspeccionar con cuidado el [mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) antes de publicar la pregunta..

  Debería apuntar a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Además que le sobra un punto **"."** a esa oración después de pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por publicar esto.  ¡Las revisiones se han terminado!